# Change numbers of a vector based on "group" size

Tags: r

I have an integer vector called `x`, and I would like to change the values based on the "group" size, in order (from biggest to smallest).

Here's the `dput`:

```
c(6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 6, 5, 2, 4, 
2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 5, 5, 2, 6, 6,
5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 6,
2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 6, 2,
6, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 5,
5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6)
```

Here's the output from `table`:

```
> table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6
 1 20  2  8 15 22
```

So the `6`'s in `x` should become `1`'s (because `6` appears most often), the `2`'s' should become `2`, the `5`'s should become `3`, etc.

Does anyone know of an elegant way to do this? I partially came up with a solution involving `as.integer(names(table[rev(order(table))]))` but that is exceedingly ugly.

---

EDIT: @Richard Scriven's answer worked for some of my vectors, but something strange happens when the number of "groups" (i.e. the number of unique integers) gets larger. Here's another example:

```
> dput(x)
c(8, 1, 2, 8, 15, 15, 8, 15, 3, 8, 13, 8, 15, 15, 4, 8, 5, 13, 
13, 13, 8, 6, 15, 8, 7, 13, 13, 8, 15, 8, 14, 13, 15, 15, 15, 
13, 13, 8, 15, 15, 8, 15, 9, 8, 15, 8, 15, 15, 15, 15, 13, 15, 
13, 10, 8, 11, 13, 8, 12, 13, 13, 8, 15, 8, 14, 15, 16, 15)

> table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1 18  1  1  1  1 14  2 22  1 

> tbl <- sort(table(x), decreasing=T)
> tbl
x
15  8 13 14  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9 10 11 12 16 
22 18 14  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 

> x.new <- as.integer(names(tbl))[x]
> table(x.new)
x.new
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
 1  1  1 18  1  1  1  1  1 14  2 22  1  1  1  1
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

---

EDIT 2: A solution that seems to work would be looping:

```
for (i in seq_along(tbl)) {
  x.new[which(x == as.integer(names(tbl))[i])] <- i
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't use all 16 values from `x`

Comment: In your edited `x`, how do you handle 'ties', where e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, and 16 all occur once?

Comment: @tospig For my use case it doesn't matter, as the updated numbers are arbitrary (as long as they're in decreasing order of size).

Comment: In that case I think @RichardScriven's method still works. Why have you `table(x.new)` 'ed the result?

Comment: Because even though ties are arbitrary, the output of `table(x.new)` should still be `22 18 14 2 1 ...`.

Comment: It is. But you're now `tabling` on the new/replacement values of `x`, where your original 8 got changed to 4, and in the `x.new` vector, 4 occurs 18 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea with `order` to avoid some conversions and splitting:

```
x2 = match(x, order(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))
table(x)
#x
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
# 1  1  1  1  1  1  1 18  1  1  1  1 14  2 22  1 
table(x2)
#x2
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
#22 18 14  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
x2[x == 14]
#[1] 4 4
x2[x == 8]
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I've checked on multiple vectors and this seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You could `sort()` the table, then use the names from the table with vector indexing on `x`.

```
tbl <- sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)
as.integer(names(tbl))[x]  ## or rank(names(tbl))[x]
```

which gives

```
#  [1] 1 3 3 2 1 1 2 1 5 2 4 2 4 1 6 2 1 3 2 4 2 2 1 2 4 3 3 2 1 1 3 3
# [33] 1 1 1 3 3 2 1 1 2 1 5 2 4 2 4 1 1 2 1 3 3 4 2 2 3 2 4 3 3 2 1 2
# [65] 3 1 1 1
```

where

```
x <- c(6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 6, 5, 2, 4, 
2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 5, 5, 2, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 6, 2, 
6, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 6, 2, 6, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 5, 5, 2, 
6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6)
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew there was a simple way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RichardScriven I made an edit to the OP because this method didn't work for other vectors. If you get a chance, please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer but @alexis_laz gave an answer that seems to work better for my data.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave`:

```
as.integer(as.factor(-ave(x,x,FUN=length)))
# [1] 1 3 3 2 1 1 2 1 5 2 4 2 4 1 6 ....
```